# CLI command to add files to gitignore

Tags: bash, git, command-line-interface, gitignore

I'm working in a highly nested project and want to add some files to gitignore from the shell, but it's a bit of a pain working relative paths.

I can do a one liner like this (wrapped for legibility):

```
echo file |
xargs -n1 greadlink -f |
xargs realpath --relative-to=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) \
  > $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.gitignore
```

but if feels like there should be something a better like `git addtoignore file`. Is there a simple, reliable command I can use to add a file to the gitignore without dealing with relative path names.

Comment: Is there a reason for not adding it to the local `.gitignore` (`echo "/file" >> .gitignore`)?

Comment: Just that getting relative paths is a real pain in highly nested folders (that's what the above command is about). I've tweaked the command so that it writes to .gitignore (and so is the "general" equivalent of your commadn).

Comment: You don't need to have a single .gitignore at the root of the repo, you can have other gitignore files in nested directories. It might help simplify to split it out across multiple files.

Comment: If `file` is already relative to the current directory from which you run all this, you do not need to worry about relative paths. Just add `/file` to a `.gitignore` file in the same directory.

Comment: @cmbuckley Yeah maybe multiple gitignores is the way to go in highly nested repos.

Comment: Is the `command-line-interface` tag needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beside using multiple .gitignore, allowing you to add `file` directly, the other approach is to use [`find`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html), assuming your `file` name is unique enough.

```
cd /path/to/repo
find . -name "file" >> .gitignore
```